# Can't debug file from dependency with browser debugger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I know Next.js development mode for React 18 is server side rendered by default, but this seems to prevent step debugging dependencies in browser, which I think worked with react-scripts for React 17.

I have following `requester` object from an imported dependency installed with `npm`.

When I try to step into the function call

[image]

[image]

the debugger does not `step into` the function, it proceeds and finishes the process.

The file which uses `requester.request()` has already `"use client"` on the first line.

Any ideas how to debug dependencies in Next.js?